# Return a large power (mod 2^32)

Tags: java, algorithm, math, exponentiation

I need to work out a very large power modulo (2^32), i.e. I want the result of:

```
y = (p^n) mod (2^32)

p is a prime number
n is a large integer
```

Is there a trick to doing this efficiently in Java?

Or am I stuck with doing it in a loop with n iterations?

Comment: Just use an `int`. And if the number is negative at the end, add `2^32`.

Comment: @Mysticial Adding `2^32` to an `int` is the same as adding `0` to an `int` (unless using the `long` result of this addition).

Comment: @jlordo Well, I obviously left out the cast to `long`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple way to mod 2^32 is to use `& 0xFFFFFFFFL`.  Also, there happens to be a type which naturally keeps the lowest 32-bit called `int` ;)  If you use that you don't even need to perform the `&` until you have the result (so the answer is unsigned)  For this reason you only need to keep the last 32 bit of the answer.  To speed up the `^n` you can calculate the square, it's square and it's square etc, e.g if n is 0b11111 then you need to multiply p^16 * p^8 * p^4 * p^2 * p.

In short, you can use plain `int` as you only need 32-bit of accuracy and values with a cost of O(ln n) where `n` is the power.

```
int prime = 2106945901;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    long answer1 = BigInteger.valueOf(prime)
                             .modPow(
                                 BigInteger.valueOf(prime), 
                                 BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(32)).longValue();

    long mid = System.nanoTime();
    int answer2 = 1;
    int p = prime;
    for (int n = prime; n > 0; n >>>= 1) {
        if ((n & 1) != 0)
            answer2 *= p;
        p *= p;
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf("True answer %,d took %.3f ms, quick answer %,d took %.3f ms%n",
            answer1, (mid - start) / 1e6, answer2 & 0xFFFFFFFFL, (end - mid) / 1e6);
}
```

prints finally

```
True answer 4,169,684,317 took 0.233 ms, quick answer 4,169,684,317 took 0.002 ms
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer and works very efficiently (which is exactly what I was looking for in the question!).

Answer (score 4):

You can utilize [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Firstly, break it down into powers of two for your given `n`. Since `p^n (mod x)  == p^(k1) (mod x) . p^(k2) (mod x) . ... p^(kn) (mod x)` where `sum k_i = n`, you can utilize this and successive powers of two to calculate this in `O(log n)` steps.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers you can use some elementary number theory to reduce the time needed to compute a<sup>n</sup> mod 2<sup>32</sup> for `a` an odd integer to O(1). The [Euler Phi function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_phi) together with [Euler's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) allows you to discard all but the low-order 31 bits of n.

φ(2<sup>32</sup>) = 2<sup>31</sup>, and a<sup>φ(2<sup>32</sup>)</sup> = 1 mod 2<sup>32</sup>.

Thus if n = q*(2<sup>31</sup>) + r, 0 <= r < 2<sup>31</sup>, then a<sup>n</sup> mod 2<sup>32</sup> = a<sup>r</sup> mod 2<sup>32</sup>

r is simply the low-order 31 bits of n, i.e. `n & 0x7fffffff`. In fact, by [Carmichael's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) you can do a bit better (literally), and you only need to consider the low-order 30 bits of n, i.e. `n & 0x3fffffff`. You can precompute these once and store them in a table of size 4GB for a given base `a`. Here is some java code as an example.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class PowMod2_32 {

    private static final long MASK32 = 0xffffffffL;

    public static long pow32(final int a, final int exponent)
    {
        int prod = 1;

        for (int i = 29; i>=0; i--) {
            prod *= prod; // square
            if (((exponent >> i) & 1) == 1) {
                prod *= a;  // multiply
            }
        }
        return prod & MASK32;
    }

    public static long pow32(BigInteger a, BigInteger exponent) {
        return pow32(a.intValue(), exponent.intValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no tricks in java that I know of but rather there are some tricks in maths.

If you implement  [these](http://gmatclub.com/forum/compilation-of-tips-and-tricks-to-deal-with-remainders-86714.html)  as an algorithm it should speed up computation.

Look at 5 and 6. Look at 4 also if power of two is always even

Comment: You should summarize that link into your answer. Otherwise, it's just another link-only answer that isn't useful should the link ever break.

Comment: Yep I'll do that in a bit. Sorry I'm typing on a phone and its complicated maths

Answer (score -2):

Use the Class Bigintiger. here´s an example how to work / pow  with it

```
public String higherPow() {
    BigIntiger i = new Bigintger("2");
    // doing a power(2^32)
    i = i.pow(32);
    // after 2^32 was made, do mod 100
    i = i.mod(new Bigintiger("100"));
    return i.toString();
}
```

Comment: `BigInteger` is more than overkill for this.

Comment: -1.  You're computing a string representation of `2**32 % 100` (or at least you would be if you corrected the three different misspellings of `BigInteger`).  This isn't even close to what the OP requested.